# Assign a name to variable according to user

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Say I am creating a function named `register(name)`, and I want to assign a variable in it in the name of the variable name, like I pass:-

```js
 function register(oidu){
var oidu = "idk";
}
```

and then I pass again:-

```js
 function register(lol){
var lol = "idk";
}
```

You may observe that the variable is named as the name(value passed in function). I want to do like this in reality. How can I do this?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? It sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/398364).

Comment: You can set these variables in the global scope (window object) using bracket notation, i.e. `window['lol'] = 'idk'`. What are you actually trying to do here, though? There isn't really a good use case for this pattern.